# Error on Highchart import within mocha unit test

Tags: node.js, typescript, highcharts, mocha.js, commonjs

Has anyone been able to unit test [Highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) with [mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha). Everything works great when we deploy our code, but it looks like it might not be possible to load the [highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) package out side of the browser.

Our code repro is Typescript, so we use ts-node to transpile to commonJS, and run tests with mocha and Domino to fake out the window/document, which we use for testing our other React components.

Specifically the side effects of calling import trigger the TypeError:

```
import * as _Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Which triggers this stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'hcTimezoneOffset' of undefined
    at A (<MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:113:299)
    at <MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:119:497
    at <MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:119:502
    at a (<MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:8:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:8:109)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (<MyPath>/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:373:14)
```

Which is referencing this code snippet.

```
    <MyPath>/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:113
a.defaultOptions.global,k=q.moment;if(g.timezone){if(k)return function(a){return-k.tz(a,g.timezone).utcOffset()};a.error(25)}return g.useUTC&&g.getTimezoneOffset}function A(){var g=a.defaultOptions.global,u,h=g.useUTC,e=h?"getUTC":"get",n=h?"setUTC":"set";a.Date=u=g.Date||q.Date;u.hcTimezoneOffset=h&&g.timezoneOffset;u.hcGetTimezoneOffset=C();u.hcMakeTime=function(a,c,e,b,n,g){var d;h?(d=u.UTC.apply(0,arguments),d+=m(d)):d=(new u(a,c,k(e,1),k(b,0),k(n,0),k(g,0))).getTime();return d};F("Minutes Hours Day Date Month FullYear".split(" "),
```

The code is a bit hard to follow minified, but looks like the root cause is `a.defaultOptions.global` is `undefined` for whatever reason. I'm digging in further, but curious if anyone else has gotten a similar setup to work. Its likely that our test Domino window is confusing the [highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) code.

Answer (score 3):

So unminfying the highcharts code lead me to the answer. The failing block is here.

```
var g = a.defaultOptions.global,
    u, h = g.useUTC,
    e = h ? "getUTC" : "get",
    n = h ? "setUTC" : "set";
    a.Date = u = g.Date || q.Date;
    u.hcTimezoneOffset = h && g.timezoneOffset;
```

The global defaultOptions are initialized as so, which is important to note, no Date key is ever set, nor anywhere else that I can see.

```
global: {
  useUTC: !0,
  VMLRadialGradientURL: "http://code.highcharts.com/5.0.12/gfx/vml-radial-gradient.png"
}
```

It looks like it assumes it will find a Date key in the globalOptions or on q.Date, and q is set to the window. Our domino window was now exposing a Date method to mimic a native browser window. Adding that seems to make everything run smoothly. Not the most intuitive failure though.

Would be nice the if the import did not have so many side effects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it looks like conflict of Highchart and JSDOM that I'm using for testing. 
Window object provided by JSDOM lacks of Date object, so I just added

```
global.window.Date = Date;
```

and Highcharts import succeeded.